# What is the best ROS distribution for a wheeled robot in 2020?

Tags: ros, robotics, gazebo-simu

I cant manage to figure out which ROS distribution is better for certain purposes. In the past I used the lunar distribution which was the newest one but they keep releasing newer ones and with little information on their advantages/disadvantages or features. The only thing they show is how to do the migration and a couple of more installation instructions.

[Here](http://wiki.ros.org/Distributions) is the list of the distributions available.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would recommend ROS Melodic Morenia, since it runs on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, it depends on the case. Are you in a university lab experimenting/or a student that potentially look for a job in a couple of years? It might be nice to invest time in ROS2 Eloquent. You work in a company, and you want to ensure high stability and compatibility, go for ROS1 Melodic.

Comment: Yes, I believe that I will try out ROS2 as in the future it will probably be the distribution of preference. Does it add any functionality that we cannot find in ROS1?

Comment: Yes, there are many new things that is for sure. The easiest way to get a taste is this [infograph](https://www.theconstructsim.com/infographic-ros-1-vs-ros-2-one-better-2/). Want more? Check this [one](http://design.ros2.org/articles/changes.html)

Comment: Thanks, please accept the anwser if you are ok with that :)